# Dialog modal not closing

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem with a dialog modal who don,t want to close even with a function

I have this code to reset and close the modal, the resetting is ok but nothing close with cancel, I use the resetForm() function
I have a form with this structure ( form and rules )

```
<template>
    <div class="text-center">
        <v-dialog
                v-model="dialog"
        >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn class="addGroup" v-on="on">Add a group</v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-form
                    ref="form"
                    v-model="valid"
                    lazy-validation
            >

            <v-card>
                <v-card-title
                        class="headline grey lighten-2"
                        primary-title
                >
                    Add a group
                </v-card-title>

                    <v-stepper v-model="e1">
                        <v-stepper-header class="stepHeader">
                            <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 1" step="1">Choose a name</v-stepper-step>

                            <v-divider></v-divider>

                            <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 2" step="2">Select fixtures</v-stepper-step>

                            <v-divider></v-divider>

                            <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 3" step="3">Apply a recipe</v-stepper-step>

                            <v-divider></v-divider>

                            <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 4" step="4" >Select dates</v-stepper-step>

                            <v-divider></v-divider>

                            <v-stepper-step step="5">Summary</v-stepper-step>
                        </v-stepper-header>

                        <v-stepper-items>
                            <v-stepper-content  step="1" class="mt-6">
                                <v-card
                                >
                                    <div class="step chooseName">
                                        <h3>Create a group</h3>

                                        <p class="mt-12">Choose a name for your group</p>
                                        <v-text-field
                                                :rules="rules.name"
                                                @keyup.enter="e1 = 2"
                                                v-model="form.groupName"
                                        ></v-text-field>


                                    </div>
                                </v-card>

                                <v-btn
                                        color="primary"
                                        @click="e1 = 2"
                                >
                                    Continue
                                </v-btn>

                                <v-btn
                                        text
                                        @click="dialog = !dialog"
                                >
                                    Cancel</v-btn>
                            </v-stepper-content>

                            <v-stepper-content step="2" class="mt-6">
                                <v-card
                                >
                                    <div class="step selectFixtures">
                                        <h3><v-icon @click="e1 = 1">mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>Select fixtures</h3>

                                        <p class="mt-12 mb-6"

                                        >Choose fixtures you want associate with {{form.groupName}}.</p>
                                        <v-select
                                                :rules="rules.fixture"
                                                v-model="form.selectedFixture"
                                                :items="fixtures"
                                                item-text="name"
                                        ></v-select>
                                    </div>
                                </v-card>

                                <v-btn
                                        color="primary"
                                        @click="e1 = 3"
                                >
                                    Continue
                                </v-btn>

                                <v-btn
                                        text
                                        @click="dialog = !dialog"
                                >
                                    Cancel</v-btn>
                            </v-stepper-content>
                            <v-stepper-content step="3" class="mt-6">
                                <v-card
                                        flat
                                        height="68vh"
                                        rounded
                                >

                                    <div class="step applyRecipe">
                                        <h3><v-icon @click="e1 = 2">mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>Apply a recipe to your group</h3>

                                        <p class="mt-12 mb-6">Select a recipe for the group {{groupName}}.</p>
                                        <div class="selectRecipe">
                                            <v-select
                                                    class="mr-6"

                                                    v-model="form.selectedRecipe"
                                                    :items="recipe"
                                                    item-text="name"
                                                    item-value="duration"
                                                    return-object>
                                            </v-select>
                                            <p>or</p>
                                            <create_recipe></create_recipe>
                                        </div>


                                    </div>
                                </v-card>
                                <v-btn
                                        color="primary"
                                        @click="e1 = 4"

                                >
                                    Continue
                                </v-btn>

                                <v-btn
                                        text
                                        @click="dialog = !dialog"
                                >
                                    Cancel</v-btn>
                            </v-stepper-content>

                            <v-stepper-content step="4" class="mt-6">
                                <v-card
                                >
                                    <div class="selectDates">
                                        <h3><v-icon @click="e1 = 3">mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>Select start date</h3>

                                        <p class="mt-6">Select the launch date of the Tuscan sun recipe for the {{groupName}} group</p>
                                        <p>The end date will be set automatically according to the parameters of your recipe</p>
                                        <v-date-picker
                                                class="mt-6 ml-6"
                                                v-model="selectedDate"
                                                no-title
                                                :date-format="date => new Date(date).toDateString()"
                                        >
                                        </v-date-picker>
                                    </div>
                                </v-card>

                                <v-btn
                                        color="primary"
                                        @click="e1 = 5"

                                >
                                    Continue
                                </v-btn>

                                <v-btn
                                        text
                                        @click="dialog = !dialog"
                                >
                                    Cancel</v-btn>
                            </v-stepper-content>

                            <v-stepper-content step="5" class="mt-6">
                                <v-card
                                >
                                    <div class="stepChooseName">
                                        <h3><v-icon @click="e1 = 4">mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>Summary</h3>

                                        <p class="answer">Group name :</p>
                                        <p class="subtitle">{{form.groupName}}</p>
                                        <v-divider></v-divider>

                                    </div>
                                </v-card>

                                <v-btn
                                        @click="submit()"
                                >
                                    Add group
                                </v-btn>

                                <v-btn
                                        text
                                        @click="dialog = !dialog"
                                >
                                    Cancel</v-btn>
                            </v-stepper-content>
                        </v-stepper-items>
                    </v-stepper>
            </v-card>
            </v-form>
        </v-dialog>
    </div>
</template>
```

I have this code to reset and close the modal, the resetting is ok but nothing close with cancel, I use the resetForm() function
I have a form with this structure ( form and rules )

````
<script>

    import Create_recipe from "./create_recipe";
    export default {
        components: {Create_recipe},
        props: ['groups', 'fixtures'],
        groups: [],
        data() {
            const defaultForm = Object.freeze({
                groupName: '',
                selectedFixture: [],
                selectedRecipe: '',
                selectedScenario: '',
            });
            return {
                form: Object.assign({}, defaultForm),
                valid: true,
                rules: {
                    name: [val => (val || '').length > 0 || 'This field is required'],
                    fixture: [val => (val || '').length > 0 || 'fixture is required'],
                    recipe: [val => (val || '').length > 0 || 'recipe is required'],
                },
                dialog: null,
                defaultForm,
                e1:0,
                counterOfUnnamed:'',
                checkbox: true,
                fixtures: this.fixtures,
                selectedDate: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),

                recipe: [{
                        id:1,
                        name: 'Tuscan sun',
                        duration: '5',
                    },
                    {   id:2,
                        name: 'Montreal summer',
                        duration: '10',
                    },
                    {   id:3,
                        name: 'French spring',
                        duration: '365',
                    }
                ],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            numberOfFixture() {
                return this.form.selectedFixture.length;
                },
            resetForm () {
                this.$refs.form.reset();
                this.dialog = false
            },
            submit() {
                if (!this.form.groupName) {
                    this.form.groupName = "Unnamed" + this.counterOfUnnamed;
                    this.counterOfUnnamed = this.counterOfUnnamed + 1;
                    this.counterOfUnnamed = parseInt(this.counterOfUnnamed);
                }
                var self = this;
                http.post('group/create', {
                    name: self.form.groupName,
                }).then((result) => {
                    self.groups.push(result);
                    self.resetForm();
                })


            },

            },
        computed: {
            displayFixturesName() {
                return this.form.selectedFixture.join(', ');
                },

            formIsValid() {
                return (
                    this.form.selectedFixture &&
                    this.form.selectedRecipe
                )
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But when I launch the reset function, the form is reset but the validation appears.

How can I solve it ?
````

Comment: Could you include the template code that uses `dialog`?

Comment: now, post edited ,

Comment: I don't see anywhere that your template uses the property `dialog`. Nor do I see anywhere that it is using the `v-dialog` component. Your `resetForm` method mentions `$refs.form` but I don't see a `ref` defined anywhere. The template also has multiple root nodes, which isn't valid.

Comment: sorry , new update

Comment: The only thing that seems to be changing the `dialog` property is the `submit` method but nothing seems to be calling that. Can you also please sort out the indentation in your template so that we can make sense of it?

Comment: I edit my code for the submit function, but the resetForm() did close the form

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in above code, check in console, "this" keyword in Vue js should not  use inside fat array functions. By default the current context points to main Vue instance in any Vue components, methods and computed properties. Using this will change the reference. In this code, it gets struck when you are calling this.groups.push(result)

Better preserve the this reference and try to achieve the same by putting resetForm inside then block

```
submit() {
    var self = this;
    http.post('group/create', {
      name: self.form.groupName,
    }).then((result) => {
      self.groups.push(result)
      self.resetForm();
      // still you face issue add this line here "self.dialog = false;"
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // handle error
    });
  },
```

> Your updated script:

```
<script>

    import Create_recipe from "./create_recipe";

const defaultForm = Object.freeze({
                groupName: '',
                selectedFixture: [],
                selectedRecipe: '',
                selectedScenario: '',
            });

    export default {
        components: {Create_recipe},
        props: ['groups', 'fixtures'],
        groups: [],
        data() {

            return {
                form: Object.assign({}, defaultForm),
                valid: true,
                rules: {
                    name: [val => (val || '').length > 0 || 'This field is required'],
                    fixture: [val => (val || '').length > 0 || 'fixture is required'],
                    recipe: [val => (val || '').length > 0 || 'recipe is required'],
                },
                dialog: null,
                defaultForm,
                e1:0,
                counterOfUnnamed:'',
                checkbox: true,
                fixtures: this.fixtures,
                selectedDate: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),

                recipe: [{
                        id:1,
                        name: 'Tuscan sun',
                        duration: '5',
                    },
                    {   id:2,
                        name: 'Montreal summer',
                        duration: '10',
                    },
                    {   id:3,
                        name: 'French spring',
                        duration: '365',
                    }
                ],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            numberOfFixture() {
                return this.form.selectedFixture.length;
                },
            resetForm () {
                this.$refs.form.reset();
                this.dialog = false
            },
            submit() {
                if (!this.form.groupName) {
                    this.form.groupName = "Unnamed" + this.counterOfUnnamed;
                    this.counterOfUnnamed = this.counterOfUnnamed + 1;
                    this.counterOfUnnamed = parseInt(this.counterOfUnnamed);
                }
                var self = this;
                http.post('group/create', {
                    name: self.form.groupName,
                }).then((result) => {
                    self.groups.push(result);
                    self.form = Object.assign({}, defaultForm);
                    self.dialog = false;
                })


            },

            },
        computed: {
            displayFixturesName() {
                return this.form.selectedFixture.join(', ');
                },

            formIsValid() {
                return (
                    this.form.selectedFixture &&
                    this.form.selectedRecipe
                )
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201028/discussion-on-answer-by-chans-dialog-modal-not-closing).

Comment: there's no way to solve it but I think I have a problem with the this.$refs.form.reset();
When I comment it , it close but no resetting.
What's the solution

Comment: Try to do console.log(this.$refs.form) to check whether you can able to access

Comment: For reseting stepper , I have given answer in codepen https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/wvvzddP